# Identifying a differentiable function $\mu$ satisfying $\mu (t)=t^2\int _1^t\frac{1-\mu '(\tau )}{\tau ^3}d\tau $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Ascription to an initial value problem.

> Identify the differentiable function $\mu :(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, which satisfies
>
> $$\mu (t)=t^2\int _1^t\frac{1-\mu '(\tau )}{\tau ^3}d\tau $$
>
> for all $t > 0$.

I'm having difficulty understanding the approach for solving this particular problem and would be very grateful if someone could provide an impulse to guide my thinking.

Comment: Perhaps you can share some context, background, and/or your thoughts regarding this problem. Anyway, try multiplying $t^{-2}$ and differentiating both sides of the equation.

Comment: @SangchulLee, I just read the problem as I wrote it here. I realized that my issue stemmed from my fragmented knowledge of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which caused me to get stuck. Nevertheless, with your assistance, I was able to make progress with the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is equivalent to $\frac{\mu(t)}{t^2}=\int_1^t\frac{1-\mu'(\tau)}{\tau^3}d\tau$ and by differentiation you get $\frac{\mu'(t)}{t^2}-\frac{2\mu(t)}{t^3}=\frac{1-\mu'(t)}{t^3}$ so a necessary condition for $\mu$ is to be solution of the following classical differential equation :
$$(t+1)\mu'(t)-2\mu(t)=1$$ with condition $\mu(1)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac {\mu (t)}{t^2} = \int _1^t \frac{1-\mu '(\tau )}{\tau ^3}d\tau $$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left (\frac {\mu (t)}{t^2}\right ) =\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int _1^t \frac{1-\mu '(\tau )}{\tau ^3}d\tau \right )=\left [\gamma (\tau )=\frac{1-\mu '(\tau)}{\tau ^3}\right ]=\frac{d}{dt}\left (\Gamma (\tau) \bigg| _{\tau =1}^{\tau =t} \right )$$
$$\frac {t^2\cdot \mu '(t)-2t\cdot \mu (t)}{t^4}=\frac {d}{dt}\big ( (\Gamma (t)-\Gamma (1)\big ) =\gamma (t)=\frac {1-\mu' (t)}{t^3}$$

$$\frac {t^2\cdot \mu '(t)+2t\cdot \mu (t)}{t^4}=\frac {1-\mu '(t)}{t^3}$$
$$\mu '(t)-\frac {2}{t+1}\cdot \mu (t)=\frac{1}{t+1}$$

Homogeneous solution:
$$\mu '(t)-\frac {2}{t+1}\cdot \mu (t)=0$$
$$\int \frac {\mu '(t)}{\mu (t)}dt-2\int \frac{1}{t+1}dt=C$$
$$\mu (t)=\chi \cdot (t+1)^2$$

Inhomogeneous solution:
$$\chi '(t)(t+1)^2+\chi(t)\cdot 2\cdot (t+1)-\frac{2}{t+1}\cdot \chi (t)\cdot(t+1)^2=\frac{1}{t+1}$$
$$\chi (t)=\int \frac{1}{(t+1)^3}dt$$
$$\chi (t)=-\frac{1}{2\cdot (t+1)^2}+\theta$$

Initial value problem: $$\mu (1)=0 \Rightarrow \theta = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\mu (t)=\left (-\frac{1}{2\cdot (t+1)^2}+\frac{1}{2}\right )\cdot (t+1)^2$$

$$$$

Thank you all for your help. Here is my solution. If anyone notices anything wrong at a glance, I would appreciate corrections.